# Доступ к элементу ListView по позиции и изменение элемента

Tags: java, android, listview

Привет. В одном активити есть lv, элемент состоит из нескольких вьюшек. В другом 2 edittext и кнопка. Нужно ввести номер строки из lv и новое значение прогресса в прогрессбар.

Как получить доступ к элементу по позиции (передается из второго активити), а после изменить атрибут вьюшки из этого элемента? 
Вот что есть:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

main.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AfterClickActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivity(intent);

}
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
      int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);
      int progr = getIntent().getIntExtra("progress",0)*100;
      View view = (View) getListAdapter().getItem(pos);
      ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
      pb.setProgress(progr);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Integer[] array = new Integer[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.tvText, array);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Элемент списка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:progress="70"
        android:layout_gravity="end"/>

    <Button
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:focusable="false"/>
</FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/arrowright"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

settings.java (где вводим номер строки и новое значение)

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText editRow;
EditText editPercent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    editPercent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPercent);
    editRow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRow);


}
public void setClick (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("progress",editPercent.getText());
    intent.putExtra("position",editRow.getText());
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Перефразируйте первый абзац чтоб было понятно в чем проблема

Comment: Окей. Сейчас я передаю данные в мэйнактивити (номер строки и процент заполнения прогрессбара). В мэйнактивити хочу изменить прогресс прогрессбара из элемента списка с номером, который передали из второго активити. Как это делаю, видно в коде. При нажатии на кнопку бросается classcastexception и ругается на View view = (View) getListAdapter().getItem(pos);

Comment: Разобрался. View item = getListView().getChildAt(pos);

Answer (score 1):

Для начала не понятно описание вашей проблемы, опробуйте перефразировать.

Но из кода я вижу что у вас из `MainActivity` при клике на кнопку стартует `SettingsActivity`, а потом вы оттуда опять стартуете еще одно `MainActivity` с 2 параметрами вместо того чтобы просто вернуть результат в существующее `MainActivity`.  Для того чтобы вернуть результат нужно в `MainActivity` вместо `startActivity` использовать `startActivityForResult` и переопределить метод `onActivityResult`, куда будет приходит результат. А в `SettingsActivity` просто вызывать `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)` и`finish()`.

Comment: Так тоже пробовал. В этой строчке: View view = (View) getListAdapter().getItem(pos);
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar); все корректно???